# What are the most common dangerous domains that I should block?

Tags: firewall, malware, privacy-protection

I am trying to configure my wireless router to block domains that are potentially dangerous to  privacy, security, and bandwidth-hogs. Is there a list of domains that I can block at the router level? On a machine level, I have set the hosts file from www.mvps.org and that works on my machine. However, I want to implement something at the router level too - so that all computers in my household are somewhat protected.

Comment: The way the question's been asked would lead me to think of this as something community wiki.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider an [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com) setup to start with

- [List of Black Listed Domains: Known Scam Sites](http://www.ixibo.com/2009/02/black-listed-domains-list-scam-sites/)
- [Blacklist Compared](http://www.sdsc.edu/~jeff/spam/Blacklists_Compared.html), and the lists

  - [www.rfc-ignorant.org/](http://www.rfc-ignorant.org/)
  - [www.spamhaus.org/](http://www.spamhaus.org/)
  - [www.dnsbl.sorbs.net/](http://www.dnsbl.sorbs.net/)
  - [spamcop.net/bl.shtml](http://spamcop.net/bl.shtml)
- [DNS Providers Blacklist](http://dnsbl.org/) -- probably not for you (just a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL))
- [Blacklist Check](http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) -- may be interesting too
- NetworkWorld article [DNS 'blacklist' unveiled](http://www.networkworld.com/news/2009/081809-dns-blacklist.html)
  that is just a further-reading reference

Answer (score 1):

my router download and execute this rule everyday:
http://www.emergingthreats.net/rules/